# Handling command line options before and after an argument in C

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, getopt

So far I've been using [`getopt_long`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options) to parse options for a command line C program.

Is there a way to stop `getopt_long` parsing when it hits a non-option argument? If not, what's the best way to handle this in C?

To give an example, I'd like to handle commands in a similar way to [git](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/), and have general arguments before a command, and command-specific arguments after it:

```
git [general options] <command> [command options]
```

e.g.:

```
git --bare commit -a
git -p --bare status -s
```

`-p` and `--bare` are general options, and can be used with all commands, whereas `-a` is specific to the `commit` command, and `-s` specific to the `status` command.

Using `getopt_long` will try and parse all the options first, and then leave the non-option arguments to be handled.  I'd ideally like to stop parsing once I hit a non-option (i.e. the command), and then pass the remaining arguments to a command-specific option parser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GNU Getopt manual says:

> POSIX demands the following behavior: The first non-option stops option processing. This mode is selected by either setting the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT or beginning the options argument string with a plus sign (‘+’).

Comment: +1. It's funny how this appears in the Linux Programmer's Manual, i.e. the Linux manpages, but not in the "authorative" [Glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options).

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I'd been staring too long at getopt_long documentation and not enough at `man getopt`!